# Update Multiple Records with Same ID

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures

I am working on ASP.NET MVC Project. I need help in updating records to my table.

Basically I have a dropdown in my application in which when user selects list from dropdown, **Download** option will be provided where user can download **csv**.

Here inside CSV i have many rows of records. But all these rows have same **categoryid**. Say for example, I have three rows in my csv, then all these three rows have same categoryid.

Now problem i am facing is when user upload files, I need to save that in database. So here what is happening is, if csv file has three rows then last row result is being saved in all three rows.

**This is my code:**

```
  DataTable upCSV = (DataTable)TempData["UploadedCSV"];

          {
                if (isHeaderAccepted)
                {

         Data_printEntities ordertable = new  Data_printEntities();


                    foreach (DataRow dr in upCSV.Rows)
                    {


      ObjectParameter getemail = new ObjectParameter("email", dr["email"].ToString());
      ObjectParameter getpassword = neObjectParameter("password",dr["password"].ToString());
     ObjectParameter getMobile = new ObjectParameter("Mobile", dr["Mobile"].ToString());
     ObjectParameter getPhone = new ObjectParameter("Phone", dr["Phone"].ToString());

  var spresults = ordertable.usp_UpdateUserData(45, 368,  getemail.Value.ToString(), getpassword.Value.ToString(), getMobile.Value.ToString(), getPhone.Value.ToString())

               ordertable.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here 45 is **id** which every use has and 368 is **dropdown session** id. This is where I am having problem. For all three rows, 45 and 368 is common.

Here if i have three rows in csv, it is looping through three times but while updating it is updating last row result with all three rows.

So how can i make my code to save, after very loop? I mean when it loop through first row and when it execute stored procedure, that result should save in my table and after that it should continue looping to second row.

How can i acheiev this?

**Update** : usp_UpdateUserData is stored procedure for updating records. This is my sp :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpdateUserData]

      @idAccount int = 0,
      @idcategory int = 0,
     @email nvarchar(100) =0, 
    @password nvarchar(50) = 0, 
     @Mobile nvarchar(50) = 0,
      @Phone nvarchar(50)

     AS
    BEGIN

    Begin
Update tblCustomer
Set  
   email = @email, password = @password, mobileNo = @Mobile, phoneNo = @Phone

   where idAccount = 45 and idCategoryL = 368

END
    End
    GO
```

Comment: What does the table you are updating look like? What is its primary key? What about usp_UpdateUserData?

Comment: @ColinYoung Hi I updated my post with stored procedure. Please have a look into that. I have primary key in column called cutid, but how can i take primary key here for same idcategory?

Comment: Please also post a sample of CSV. If you are trying to update records, how are you expecting to match different records if you are hardcoding the account and category ids? Of course it is going to update the same record each time.

Comment: @ColinYoung Hi I am trying to update existing one. Inserting new records doesn't work. My tblcustomer contains fields such as custid(primarykey), idAccount,idCategoryL,email, password, mobileNo, phoneNo. Right now i dont have primary key in front end. In my csv user can see only email, password, mobileNo, phoneNo and they can edit these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to expose the primary key to the front end so that you can identify the record you wish to update. I suspect you have some sort of unique constraint (*e.g.* `email`) that is either real (*i.e.* an actual constraint in the DB) or imagined (*i.e.* you know what makes a record unique, but haven't actually coded those rules in the DB). That should really be your primary key. I know it's popular to use an auto-increment column as a "primary key" but all that really does is obfuscate the true nature of the data.

```
UPDATE tblCustomer
   SET email = @email,
       password = @password,
       mobileNo = @Mobile,
       phoneNo = @Phone
 WHERE custid = @custId
   AND idAccount = 45 
   AND idCategoryL = 368
```

If for some reason you cannot expose `custid` to the front end, the next best solution is to use your unique constraint when updating (if you also want to update the email you will need to provide the old as well as the new):

```
UPDATE tblCustomer
SET    email = @new_email,
       password = @password,
       mobileNo = @Mobile,
       phoneNo = @Phone
WHERE  email = @old_email
       AND idAccount = 45 and idCategoryL = 368
```

I'd also recommend making `idAccount` and `idCategory` parameters.

Comment: Hi now i have primary key. I took in front end like this var getDetails = (from tblCustomer tbl in ordertables.tblCustomers
   where tbl.idCategory == dropdownsession
    select tbl.idCust).ToList(); Here i have three unique keys. Now how can i put this in my code that is here foreach (DataRow dr in upCSV.Rows){ ?

Comment: You need to include those custids in your CSV in the correct rows. It sounds like you are trying to use a single page to upload a set of users. You still need a way to tie each of the users to the record in the database, and that will be through `custid`.